# How can I join with a condition to contain one of each record type?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to use a join that will only allow one of each record type.

I am not sure how to word this, here is an example of my data set.

My goal is to have the Bundle order Item Id associated with only *one* of each item type. For context, a bundle can only contain count of shirt < = 1 AND count of pant < = 1. There cannot be two of the same item types in one bundle.

Table: Clothing

```
|Order id|Order Item ID|Item Type
|:---- |:----:| ----:|
|1|123|shirt|
|1|456|pant|
|1|789|shirt|
|1|100|pant|
```

Table: Bundle

```
|Order id|Order Item ID|
|:---- |----:| 
|1|654|
|1|321|
```

The only way these tables can join is through the order id, which would cause the following:

```
|c.Order id|c.Order Item ID|c.Item Type|b.Order id|b.Order Item ID|
|:---- |:----:| :----:|:----:| ----:|
|1|123|shirt|1|654|
|1|456|pant|1|654|
|1|789|shirt|1|654|
|1|100|pant|1|654|
|1|123|shirt|1|321|
|1|456|pant|1|321|
|1|789|shirt|1|321|
|1|100|pant|1|321|
```

When in reality I want:

```
|c.Order id|c.Order Item ID|c.Item Type|b.Order id|b.Order Item ID|
|:---- |:----:| :----:|:----:| :----:|
|1|123|shirt|1|654|
|1|456|pant|1|654|
|1|789|shirt|1|321|
|1|100|pant|1|321|
```

Essentially I need sql that will do the following:

- Join clothing.order_id = bundle.order_id
- WHERE count of shirt < = 1 AND count of pant < = 1

Two of the same item types cannot be associated with the same bundle order item id. An order item id can only have one of each item type.

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  How do you know what the limits are for the "bundle"?  And do the bundle values have to differ?  Just adding the first one seems to meet your requirements.

Comment: added redshift! Thanks

Comment: The limit is a business rule. One of each type. This will not change.

Comment: This is a case where a single order has two bundles. Because the order is on an item level i'm essentially able to see what's in each bundle. What I'm trying to do is connect the items in the order to one bundle id.  (or in this case two)

Comment: Question 'Order item_id' in the clothing table is different than 'order item_id' in the bundle table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you example, you can join on an enumerated column:

```
select c.*, b.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by order_id, item_type order by order_item_id) as seqnum
      from clothing c
     ) c
     (select b.*,
             row_numberr() over (partition by order_id order by order_item_id) as seqnum
      from bundle b
     ) b
     on c.order_id = b.order_id and c.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```

Comment: Thank you tons! I was using the row_number within the CTE that generated the output of clothing and bundle when I should've been using it at the last step!!

Answer (score 0):

Means you have no option other then joining tables based on order_id then you can use analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select c.*, b.*,
        Dense_rank() over (partition by b.order_id order by b.order_item_id) as dr_bundle,
        rank() over (partition by b.order_item_id, c.item_type order by c.order_item_id) as r_clothing
  From clothing c join bundle b on c.order_id = b.order_id) t
Where r_clothing = dr_bundle;
```